# Flexbox not working in Firefox when using aspect ratio with % padding elements

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I have managed to create a desired layout of elements per this illustration using flexbox:

[image: elements layout achieved with flexbox]

However, it doesn't seem to work in Firefox. Firefox doesn't respect the inner elements being set to keep aspect ratio. I have tried an answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871917/maintaining-the-aspect-ratio-of-divs-inside-a-flexbox-seems-to-not-work-in-firef), but it didn't help.

*Please ignore the lack of prefixes for flex directives. I am using autoprefixer in my code, so the output CSS will include them.

```css
.box {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 66.199%;
    background: #eee;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-grid {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-container {
    display: flex !important;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex: 1 !important;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-container > .flex-grid-child {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-container > .flex-grid-child:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-row, .flex-grid .flex-grid-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-column {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-column .flex-grid-child {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-column .flex-grid-child:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-column:last-of-type .flex-grid-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-mother {
    flex: 1;
    align-self: auto;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-child {
    flex: 1;
    align-self: auto;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="flex-grid-container flex-grid-mother flex-grid-row">
        <div class="flex-grid-child">
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-grid-child flex-grid-row">
            <div class="flex-grid-child flex-grid-column">
                <div class="flex-grid-child">
                    <div class="box"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-grid-child">
                    <div class="box"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-grid-child flex-grid-column">
                <div class="flex-grid-child">
                    <div class="box"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-grid-child">
                    <div class="box"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the CodePen](http://codepen.io/tomlis20/pen/EyOOkm)

Answer (score 0):

you could add to the `parent` of the `.flex-grid` , in this case `body` , a fixed height or in this case you could use `100vh`

or if you have another container use a fixed height on that one.

see snippet below

```css
body {
  height:100vh;
  }
.box {
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 66.199%;
    background: #eee;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-grid {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-container {
    display: flex !important;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex: 1 !important;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-container > .flex-grid-child {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-container > .flex-grid-child:last-of-type {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-row, .flex-grid .flex-grid-column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-column {
    flex-direction: column;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-column .flex-grid-child {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-column .flex-grid-child:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-column:last-of-type .flex-grid-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-mother {
    flex: 1;
    align-self: auto;
}
.flex-grid .flex-grid-child {
    flex: 1;
    align-self: auto;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-grid">
    <div class="flex-grid-container flex-grid-mother flex-grid-row">
        <div class="flex-grid-child">
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-grid-child flex-grid-row">
            <div class="flex-grid-child flex-grid-column">
                <div class="flex-grid-child">
                    <div class="box"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-grid-child">
                    <div class="box"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flex-grid-child flex-grid-column">
                <div class="flex-grid-child">
                    <div class="box"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex-grid-child">
                    <div class="box"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It partially works, because when applied the .box elements no longer keep their aspect ratio, which is crucial for me. Thoughts?